# Unity 2D Tilemap, and ever increasing Total Object Count

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, 2d, sprite, profiler

I'm creating a game that uses an 80x40 2D Tilemap, using procedural terrain generation.  Currently, creating the map works flawlessly, as well as re-building with a button press (as many times as I want).  And, I'm getting really great graphical performance (~800 of FPS).

However, I'm noticing that every time I rebuild the map, I get an increasing Total Object Count in the Profiler-memory section.  The increase per map re-build is around 2500 to 2700 objects.  This is not quite the full amount of tiles (3200) but is close enough that I suspect the sprite drawing as the source of the leak.

Reading online indicates that there is potentially a memory leak with the Material renderer.  I'm not sure if the method I'm using to redraw the map falls within this category or not.  Here's how I'm doing it...

I have a bunch of sprite atlases... for various auto-tiling terrain types.  Essentially, I do the following...

```c#
Vector3Int v3 = new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0);
TerrainTile theTile = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TerrainTile>();

for (int x = 0; x < theWorld.Width; x++) 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < theWorld.Height; y++) 
    {
        int nValue = theWorld.squares[x, y].tN_value[tType];
        theTile.sprite = Terrain_atr.GetAutoTileSprite(nValue);
        theTilemap.SetTile(v3, (TileBase)theTile);
    }
}
```

GetAutoTileSprite just grabs a sprite from a sprite atlas based on an auto-tile rule.

So, does the above method of painting sprites fall into the Material renderer memory leak?

I can't find any other source of objects in my code, as I simply reuse all variables every time I rebuild the map... I'm not (as far as I can see) creating anything new.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: well at least `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TerrainTile>();` creates a new object and depending whatever there happens ... and what does `GetAutoTileSprite` do?

Comment: As mentioned in the text, GetAutoTileSprite just grabs a sprite from the atlas based on a sprite name.  Nothing more.

Comment: I don't see it so I can't say ... but maybe it is not true and it actually creates copies of these Sprites instead ... otherwise hard to tell where so many new objects should come from

Comment: I did a very in depth analysis... commenting out code a bit at a time, and found the problem.  It has to do with extracting the sprite from the atlas.  I assumed that when I assigned a sprite to a tile, from the atlas, that it just essentially created a link to that sprite in the atlas.  instead, it makes a copy of some kind... even if I had just previously used that exact same sprite.  So, every time I ran though every tile on the map and assigned sprites, I was making copies.  Thus, the increasing object count…

Comment: To fix this, I now just pre-load all the sprites into an array, and assign sprites to tiles from this array.  Doing it this way doesn't result in multiple copies.  Honestly, I would argue that this is how atlases should work in the first place.

Comment: That's what I suspected from the beginning ;) I still don't know how exactly your `GetAutoTileSprite` works but if you found a solution that works you should maybe either post I as answer here including your exact changes and explanation where the issue came from .. or close the question maybe as it seems not solveable without knowing your full implementation